# Is there some way to load the TSQLConnection params from an ini file in design time?

Tags: delphi, ide

I have a SQLConnection which is shared between projects, in runtine it reads the configuration from an ini file, is there some way to load this same configuration in design time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to write your own TSQLConnection descendent.

Answer (score 3):

You have to create your own custom component for it, let's call it TCustomSQLConnection. Just drop this component on the form or on a datamodule, set up a custom property called ConfigurationFile to your ini file, and you're good to go. If I understand correctly, this is what you want - my appologies if not.

Please take a look at the following code,

```
unit uSQLCustomConnection;

interface

uses
  SysUtils, Classes, DB, SqlExpr;

type
  TCustomSQLConnection = class(TSQLConnection)
  private
    FConfigurationFile  : String;
    procedure SetConfigurationFile(Value: TStrings);
    procedure LoadConfiguration(AConfigurationFile: String);
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor  Destroy; override;
  published
    property ConfigurationFile : String read FConfigurationFile write SetConfigurationFile;
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

constructor TCustomSQLConnection.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  FConfigurationFile := '';
end;

destructor TCustomSQLConnection.Destroy;
begin
// free memory if needed
  inherited;
end;

procedure TCustomSQLConnection.SetConfigurationFile(Value: String);
begin
  FConfigurationFile := Value;
  if FileExists(FConfigurationFile) then
    LoadConfiguration(FConfigurationFile);
end;

procedure TCustomSQLConnection.LoadConfiguration(AConfigurationFile: String);
begin
// Put the code that loads the configuration here
end;

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('Samples', [TCustomSQLConnection]);
end;

end.
```

All you have to do is to install this component after adding your own code that loads the configuration, and you're good to go.

I would drop this component on a Data Module, alongside with some other components that are shared between projects.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using Delphi 2009 or 2010.  You may refer to my blog article first: http://chee-yang.blogspot.com/2008/09/delphi-2009-using-dbx4-framework.html

I have track this problem for quite some time.  In the article, there are quite a number of QC report raised.  Some already solved in Delphi 2010.  Please have a look first and we may discuss in later stage.

Comment: I think you didn't understand my question. I want to load the settings in design time, the only way I can connect to a Database in design time is by configuring the connection in the dfm, and I don't want to do that.